# Distributions of random (partial) correlations drawn from a given data matrix

Tags: correlation, references, sample, partial-correlation

**Background:** Let $X=[x_{j,k}]_{j=1,\ldots,p, k=1,\ldots,n}$ be a $p\times n$ data matrix. Each column is an i.i.d. $p$-dimensional centred random vector. One can compute the sample covariance matrix
$$S=\frac{1}{n}XX^\top$$
as well as the sample correlation matrix
$$R=(\mathrm{diag}(S))^{-1/2}S(\mathrm{diag}(S))^{-1/2}.$$
One can also obtain the partial correlations from this data matrix, while the expressions are more involved.

**Question 1:** My first questions is, if the distributions of $X$ is given, say, each entry is an i.i.d. standard Gaussian, can one write down the distribution from the correlation coefficients? Note that $R$ is also a random matrix now.

**Question 2:** Moreover, can one write down the distributions for the partial correlations? And what about the joint distribution of all partial correlations?

I presume that the answer to the first question should be known from the literature, while the expression itself could be very much involved.